# Convert text items to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have a text that includes mani list items on the next format:

```
var text = "<li>M3-2200 (da2/M3-2200)</li><li>N3-2200 (da2/N3-2200)</li><li>Picasso (picasso/A500)</li><li>Picasso (picasso/A501)</li><li>Picasso (ventana/A500)</li>..."
```

I'm trying to create JSON on the next format:

```
{
     name: "M3-2200",
     Model: "M3-2200"    
}
```

I'm trying using next code, but it doesn't work my problem is on push. anybody can explain me how do it right?

```
result ={};
while(text.indexOf("<li>")!== -1){
    var listi = text.substring(text.indexOf("<li>"), text.indexOf("</li>"));
    var model = listi.substring(0, listi.indexOf("(") -1);
    var name = listi.substring(listi.indexOf("("), listi.indexOf(")"));
    var item = {name: name: model : model};
    result.push(item);
    var text = text.substring(text.indexOf("</li>"));
}
```

Comment: There was an answer suggesting `result=[];` (instead of `result={};`) -- that is correct, result should be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solution for your problem:

```
var text = "<li>M3-2200 (da2/M3-2200)</li><li>N3-2200 (da2/N3-2200)</li><li>Picasso (picasso/A500)</li><li>Picasso (picasso/A501)</li><li>Picasso (ventana/A500)</li>";
var result = JSON.parse('[' + 
  text.replace(/(<li>|<\/li>| \(|\))/g, function(_, part){
    switch (part) {
      case '<li>': return '{"name":"';
      case '</li>': return '},';
      case ' (': return '", "Model":"';
      case ')': return '"';
    }
  }) + '0]').slice(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "<li>M3-2200 (da2/M3-2200)</li><li>N3-2200 (da2/N3-2200)</li><li>Picasso (picasso/A500)</li><li>Picasso (picasso/A501)</li><li>Picasso (ventana/A500)</li>";
JSONStr = text.trim().replace(/<li>/g,"{\"name\":\"").replace(/ \(/g,"\" , \"model\":\"").replace(/\)\<\/li\>/g,"\"},");
JSONStr = "["+JSONStr.substring(0,JSONStr.length-1)+"]";
console.log(JSONStr);
```

Will the above code work?

Comment: I think this is the best solution. But why `JSONStr.substring(0,JSONStr.length-1)` instead of just `JSONStr` on line 3?

Comment: The code adds a "," at the end. I wanted to take that out.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. If this is the output you want:

```
[{"name":"M3-2200 ","model":"da2/M3-2200"},{"name":"N3-2200 ","model":"da2/N3-2200"},{"name":"Picasso ","model":"picasso/A500"},{"name":"Picasso ","model":"picasso/A501"},{"name":"Picasso ","model":"ventana/A500"}]
```

Then this is a way to do it:

```
var text = "<li>M3-2200 (da2/M3-2200)</li><li>N3-2200 (da2/N3-2200)</li><li>Picasso (picasso/A500)</li><li>Picasso (picasso/A501)</li><li>Picasso (ventana/A500)</li>";
var extractItem = function (item) {
  var partsArray = /(.+) ?\((.+)\)\<\/li>/.exec(item)
  if(partsArray) return {"name":partsArray[1], "model":partsArray[2]}
}
var result = text.split('<li>')
  .map(extractItem)
  .filter(function(e){return e != undefined});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```